# How to change element in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

This label doesn't have an id/class.
How can I change the element from "Status" to another word in JS?:

```
 <label form="mpp-gallery-status">Status</label>
```

Comment: can you give more detail about the question??

Comment: Please share more details, go through http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Use jquery. Something like `$("label").text("new Text");`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `querySelector`/`querySelectorAll`/`getElementsByTagName` to get the label, but if you don't have any sort of identifying characteristic besides the contents of the tag then you're gonna have to do a bit of qualification on the selector:

```js
var labels = document.getElementsByTagName("label");
for (var i = 0; i < labels.length; i++) {
    var ele = labels[i];
    if (ele.getAttribute("form") == "mpp-gallery-status" && ele.innerHTML == "Status")
        ele.innerHTML = "Another word";
}
```

```html
<label form='mpp-gallery-status'>Test</label>
<br />
<label form='mpp-gallery-status'>Status</label>
```